# Quelle est la différence entre "flot" et "flux" ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'ai des difficultés à distinguer les mots "flot" et "flux" dans le contexte de l'Informatique.

Merci de me guider pour comprendre dans quel contexte on utilise chacun de ces mots.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE.  Un peu de contexte STP ?

Comment: @livresque, c'est dans l'Informatique. Merci

Comment: @Lee oui mais quoi précisément ? Donne-nous au moins une phrase d'exemple

Comment: D'une manière générale, dans le domaine scientifique on parle toujours de "flux". J'imagine qu'il en va de même pour l'informatique. Attention à ne pas associer "flot" à "float" (nombre flottant) qui n'a aucun rapport

Answer (score 5):

En informatique, on emploie plus rarement le mot ***flot*** que le mot ***flux***.

Ce dernier se rencontre plus souvent, en général pour décrire des données entrant ou sortant d'un système: ***flux entrant***, ***flux sortant***, ou parfois ***flux ascendant*** (vers Internet) et ***flux descendant*** (depuis Internet).

[image]

D'une manière plus générale, ***flot*** insiste plus sur le volume alors que ***flux*** tiens plus compte de la direction, mais les deux terme sont souvent interchangeables. Le [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8356626/flux-de-donnees) propose d'ailleurs l'un comme l'autre pour traduire *stream*.

Si on dit: *un flot de données est traité par le serveur*, ce sera souvent plus pour parler de la puissance de traitement alors que si on dit *un flux de données est traité par le serveur*, on indique un mouvement de données sans présumer du volume qu'elles occupent qui n'est pas forcément important.

On trouve aussi ***programmation par flots*** pour traduire *stream programming*.

***Flux*** a d'ailleurs pour antonyme ***reflux*** pour indiquer le mouvement inverse alors qu'il n'existe pas d'antonyme similaire pour *flot*. *Reflux* n'est guère utilisé en informatique, mais on le rencontre en médecine et en plomberie... :-)

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour l'interprétation ("flot" prend un sens de volume alors que "flux" prend un sens de mouvement) mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec la première remarque. Le flot ("stream") est très utilisé en informatique.

Comment: @BenoîtFraikin On utilise bien sûr beaucoup *stream* en informatique, en anglais comme en français, mais plus rarement le mot français *flot* que le mot *flux*.

Comment: @jlliagre des dernières années, le traitement par flots ou la programmation par flots est devenu un must. À l'origine des langages de programmation, ce fut même un des concepts essentiels fortement impliqué par les langages Lispiens. :)

Comment: @BenoîtFraikin Ok, j'ai mis de l'eau dans mon vin ;-)

Answer (score 4):

En français, un flot correspond à une masse liquide et inspire l'idée d'un mouvement. Le flux correspond lui à un mouvement que ce soit un mouvement imprimé à un gaz ou à un liquide.  Le flot est donc soumis à un flux. Et un flux implique normalement un flot.  On voit les deux se confondre par exemple dans la marée montante.  Mais le flux a une portée sémantique élargie à bien des domaines comme l'économie ou l'électromagnétisme.

En informatique, les notions essentiels sont les mêmes. Comme le dit @jlliagre, le flot représente une masse de données en mouvement (et souvent par extension le destine à un traitement) alors que le flux correspond à un mouvement de données (mais qui ne parle pas forcément de leur traitement). C'est donc dans le traitement que je verrais la différence. Il y a donc la séparation mouvement et objet en mouvement, avec la différence qui pointe la tâche : transport ou traitement. Le couple mouvement/transport devrait être référé par le mot « flux » alors que le couple données(notre objet)/traitement devrait être référé par le mot « flot ».

Le *stream programming*, ou la programmation par flots, l'accent est mis sur le volume des données qui se déplace et est traité souvent à la volée par un enchaînement de combinateurs et d'opérateurs. Les types dans les langages de programmation référant à des *streams* réfèrent à un déplacement de données en continu et souvent leurs mémorisations en tampon, mais n'impliquent pas de traitement ostensible et explicite. Et dans ce cas, on doit utiliser « flux » en français. C'est certes trompeur mais ce n'est pas la première fois que les mots s'entrecroisent dans leurs sémantiques. Quand il est temps de parler des mécanismes de contrôle qui orientent les données à l'intérieur d'un programme (*control flow*), c'est normalement le control du flux. L'accent est mis sur le mouvement et l'orientation du mouvement sans se préoccuper du traitement qui est sous-jacent. Un mécanisme de sélection de chemin (*if-then-else*) pointe le chemin et non le traitement des données sur le chemin. Le flux des données est donc différents du flot des données qui réfèrent à un volume conséquent de données qui circulent et qui pointe bien la donnée et non le mouvement. Ce flot a pour objectif d'être mémorisé/affiché/traité et l'utilisation de flot sous-entend fortement qu'il y a un traitement.

Bien sûr, d'un point de vue absolu, tout flux implique un traitement et on parle toujours de données numériques. Réciproquement, tout flot implique un mouvement et donc le transport des dites données. La différence est subtile et parfois discutable.

Plaisir des langues vivantes !

Answer (score 1):

On a besoin de contexte pour bien discerner mais les deux mots signifient **Masse de liquide ou de matière semi-liquide qui s'écoule** mais **flux** a aussi un sens scientifique signifiant *une intégrale de surface de la composante normale d'un champ vectoriel sur une surface donnée* et cette définition est souvent utilisée en mathématiques et en physique comme le flux magnétique.

Dans le cas informatique, **flux** signifie **stream** en C++ (et dans d'autres langages) comme `#include <iostream>` plus d'information (en anglais) [ici](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12145357/13826315) sur le sujet.

Comment: c'est dans l'Informatique. Merci

Comment: Ainsi le 'flot de données' signifierait une quantité de données transférée alors que 'flux' serait un méchanisme permettant de transférer (lecture/écriture) des données? Je dois avouer qu'à l'instar de nombreux autres anglicismes, je n'utilise jamais 'flux' pour stream.

Comment: Le "stream" est le "flot". Le "flow" est le "flux". C'est une erreur courante en informatique pour les francophones de confondre les termes. Le mot "flow" est un faux ami.